# Unable to use react form data in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd, redux-saga, react-forms

I have an **antd form** where I am able to get the form data in `onFinish function` upon hitting submit button in which I wanted to use `uesEffect hook` and dispatch an action with form data as payload to redux saga but I got following error

```
React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "onFinish" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.
```

**If I write useEffect hook outside the `onFinsh` function, I am unable to get the form data/values**

---

**Please suggest a workaround to get the form data values outside of    onFinish function**

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
 

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(values['username']));
    useEffect(() => {
      // dispatch an action with values as payload
     }, []);
  };
console.log(values) // UNABLE TO GET VALUES HERE...HOW TO GET IT???
  return (
    <Form
      name="basic"
      onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Dude, you cant use React Hooks inside a function, it be should react component.

Comment: @b3hr4d yeah, so is there a way I can get the form data values outside onFinish function so that I will use useEffect hook outside the function?

Comment: why you should use `useEffect`? just dispatch your action inside onFinish.

Comment: Valid question... will try that :)

Comment: To clarify why you don't need to use the hook in this case, `useEffect` is when you want side-effects to be run during a component's lifecycle, not in response to user interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't even need the `useEffect()` hook. Just dispatch the action from within the `onFinish()` and have state store the `values`

```html
const Demo = () => {

  const [ values, setValues ] = useState([]);
  
  const onFinish = (recievedValues) => {
    // dispatch here
    setValues(recievedValues);
  }
  
  console.log(values) // <-- you can get it here
  return (<div> ... </div>);
};
```

Or better yet, since you are already saving the values in redux during dispatch, you should use that in your render code as well:

```html
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Demo = () => {

  //point to the state where your data is
  const stateValues = useSelector(state => state.your.data);
  
  const onFinish = (recievedValues) => {
    // dispatch here
  }
  
  console.log(stateValues) // <-- you can get it here
  return (<div> ... </div>);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Hassan :)

Comment: Actually the initial answer of yours(`useState`) before the edit helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

useEffect can only be called at the top level of your component, not within a function. In this case, you shouldn't need useEffect to dispatch the action, and instead can just do so directly inside onFinish.